# How do I extract dates based on values of columns of a time series?

Tags: r, loops, xts

Suppose I have:

```
A <- c(1,0,0,0)
B <- c(0,1,0,0)
C <- c(0,0,1,0)
D <- c(0,0,0,1)
data <- xts(cbind(A,B,C,D),order.by = as.Date(1:4))
```

Then I get...

```
           A B C D
1970-01-02 1 0 0 0
1970-01-03 0 1 0 0
1970-01-04 0 0 1 0
1970-01-05 0 0 0 1
```

I would like to extract the dates for each column where the value is 1.
So I want to see something like this...

```
A "1970-01-02"
B "1970-01-03"
C "1970-01-04"
D "1970-01-05"
```

Here's the manual way of getting the answer. So I basically want to run a loop that can do this...

```
index(data$A[data$A==1])
index(data$B[data$B==1])
index(data$C[data$C==1])
index(data$D[data$D==1])
```

Comment: Is it important that your data is an xts object?

Comment: Can there be more than one 1 in a row?

Comment: my actual data comes from getSymbols(). that's why it's in that format. I guess I could convert it to a dataframe or something first.

Comment: yes Suren there can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for a particular row there are multiple 1's and you want to return the index only once for that row, we can use `rowSums` and subset the `index`

```
zoo::index(data)[rowSums(data == 1) > 0]
#[1] "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05"
```

If we want index value for each 1, we can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`

```
zoo::index(data)[which(data == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]]
```

---

To get both column name as well as index, we can reuse the matrix from `which`

```
mat <- which(data == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(index = zoo::index(data)[mat[, 1]], column = colnames(data)[mat[,2]])

#       index column
#1 1970-01-02      A
#2 1970-01-03      B
#3 1970-01-04      C
#4 1970-01-05      D
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the column name associated with each date?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your original `data` object, you can do create a tibble first and then melt it to get your desired format:

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(data) %>% 
  mutate(time = time(data)) %>% 
  gather("group", "value", -time) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  select(group, time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sapply`, I am returning the row names for which there is `1` in the row. This should work if there are multiples `1`'s in a row.

```
one_days <- as.Date(unlist(
    sapply(1:ncol(data), 
     function(x) time(data)[which(data[, x] == 1)])))

# "1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05"
```

If you want row names as well.

```
rown <-  unlist(sapply(1 : ncol(data), function(x) rep(colnames(data)[x], sum(data[, x]))))
names(one_days) <- rown

#           A              B            C            D
# "1970-01-02"  "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05"
```

---

Testing for multiple 1's

```
A <- c(1,1,0,0)
one_days <- as.Date(unlist(
     sapply(1:ncol(data),
      function(x) time(data)[which(data[, x] == 1)])))
rown <-  unlist(sapply(1 : ncol(data), function(x) rep(colnames(data)[x], sum(data[, x]))))
names(one_days) <- rown
one_days
#           A            A            B            C            D
#"1970-01-02" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-03" "1970-01-04" "1970-01-05"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works on the original data. But if you do more than one 1 in a column it gives the wrong result. Try using A <- c(1,1,0,0) instead.

Comment: Yes, true. I believe it is fixed now.